# How to call a method from a bean dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I use spring boot, query from database like this:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
  List<MyEntity> findAllByIdIn(List<Integer> ids);
}
```

And I want to invoke this method "findAllByIdIn" dynamically:

```
Object bean = context.getBean("myRepository");
bean.getClass().getMethod("findAllByIdIn").invoke(bean, ids);
```

I got an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.findAllByIdIn()
```

How can I invoke that method?

Answer (score 3):

[getMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) accepts 2 parameters. The first one is a method name and the second one is vararg of method parameters types.

Your code tries to get `findAllByIdIn` method without arguments, but your repository does not have it.

So the fix is:

```
bean.getClass().getMethod("findAllByIdIn", List.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.findAllByIdIn()` it is clear that your code is trying to get a method with no argument which is really not present.

So try to pass parameters also as it is expecting parameters something like below.

```
getMethod("findAllByIdIn",List.class)
```